# detecting corrupted files in ubuntu

Tags: installation, windows-7, hard-drive, filesystem

I had windows7 on my HDD. When I tried to start my laptop it hangs at a blue screen after the starting windows screen.

I then tried to reinstall windows with CD but the installation hangs too.

Finally, I installed ubuntu 12.04 on my HDD, but I want to install windows7 again.

**Question : ** What is the command like `chkdsk` in windows to check the disk in ubuntu?

I can successfully mount my drives on hdd and can access few files. When I tried to copy the files on external drives there were errors like `cannot read files` which I suspect to be the corrupted

**AIM** : To delete/recover files and reinstall windows

Also will [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/use-ubuntu-live-cd-to-backup-files-from-your-dead-windows-computer/) help ?

I also did this

```
bhavik@bhavik-Studio-1558:~$ ntfsfix -b -d /dev/sda1
Mounting volume... Error opening '/dev/sda1': Permission denied
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... Error opening '/dev/sda1': Permission denied
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Permission denied
Error opening '/dev/sda1': Permission denied
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
bhavik@bhavik-Studio-1558:~$ 
bhavik@bhavik-Studio-1558:~$
```

**UPDATE:** According the the comment and the answer I ran the command `sudo ntfsfix -b -d /dev/sda4` and the output is

```
bhavik@bhavik-Studio-1558:~$ sudo ntfsfix -b -d /dev/sda4
Mounting volume... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Invalid argument
NTFS signature is missing.
Trying the alternate boot sector
Unrecoverable error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
bhavik@bhavik-Studio-1558:~$ sudo ntfsfix -b -d /dev/sda5
Mounting volume... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Invalid argument
NTFS signature is missing.
Trying the alternate boot sector
The alternate bootsector is usable
Set sector count to 8097791 instead of 771969023
Rewriting the bootsector
The boot sector has been rewritten
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x79930316  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 51168  usa_count: 510: Invalid argument
Record 0 has no FILE magic (0x79930316)
Failed to load $MFT: Input/output error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
bhavik@bhavik-Studio-1558:~$
```

How do I uncorrupt the disk? i am thinking of formatting it using a partition manager. Is there any other way?

Comment: You should run `sudo ntfsfix -b -d /dev/sda1` to gain sufficient privileges. However check `man ntfsfix`: _ntfsfix is NOT a Linux version of chkdsk. It only repairs some fundamental NTFS inconsistencies ... and schedules an NTFS consistency check for the first boot into Windows._

Answer (score 1):

you have to try it with sudo. In past I have used this also and got same error but that statement permission denied made me try with sudo.

so you have to try with

```
sudo ntfsfix -b -d /dev/sda1
```

I am sure that going to help you.

for example , I will show my self.

```
frank@august:~$ sudo ntfsfix -b -d /dev/sda6
Mounting volume... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
Going to un-mark the bad clusters ($BadClus)... No bad clusters...OK
NTFS partition /dev/sda6 was processed successfully.
```

hope that helps.

Comment: why does it says `you should run chkdsk` ? I ran the disk turns out there some disk corrupted but it says `Unrecoverable error`

Comment: yeah, ntfsfix can't reach the specific partition unless you gave enough permissions.So when ntfsfix not reaching that partition means it will think like volume got corrupted.

Comment: so the volume may not be corrupted? also, see my update